# Get filename from wget in php

Tags: php, wget, unrar

I'm setting up a script so that I can input a URL to a web page and the script will `wget` the file. Most of the files, however, will be in the `*.rar` format. Is there anyway I can pass the filename to the `unrar` command to unarchive the files downloaded via `wget`?

Many, many thanks in advance!

**EDIT** I thought about using PHP's `explode()` function to break up the URL by the slashes (`/`) but that seems a bit hack-y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Wyzard gives the best answer. If there's a library that solves your problem, use it instead of forking an external process. It's safer and it's the clean solution. PHP's [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and [RAR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.rar.php) are good, use them.

However, if you must use `wget` and `unrar`, then @rik gives a good answer. `wget`'s `-O filename` option saves the file as `filename`, so you don't have to work it out. I would rather pipe `wget`'s output directly to `unrar` though, using `wget -q -O - http://www.example.com | unrar`.

@Byron's answer is helpful, but you really should not need to use it here. It is, however, better than using `explode()` as your edit mentions.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than forking out to external programs to download and extract the file, you should consider using PHP's own [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and [RAR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.rar.php) extensions.  You can use the [tmpfile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) function to create a temporary file, use it as the value of the CURLOPT_FILE option to make cURL save the downloaded file there, and then open that file with the RAR functions to extract the contents.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)to get the filename.

Answer (score 0):

`wget -O filename URL && unrar filename`